# Скролл в конец страницы Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

На странице данные подгружаются динамически.
Необходим метод, который будет опускать страницу до конца после подгрузки всех данных.
Пробовал `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);` но это не сработало для меня.

Comment: Должно работать. Покажите, откуда это вызываете. У vue есть хуки жизненного цикла. По ощущениям надо в mounted

Comment: если вызывать метод после подгрузки доп. контента, который влияет на высоту страницы - это не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Удалось решить вопрос с использованием [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated)

```
updated: function () {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: все-таки, не самое верное решение. `updated` - срабатывает же при любом изменении. Обычно, в таких случаях помогает запус нужного метода в `nextTick`